# Angular2 - inject singleton Service into Directive

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I have problem with injecting singleton service into a directive.
I have service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService{ ... }
```

I put it into bootstrapper.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [AuthService, ...]);
```

I made directive, that protects my component:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[protected]'
})
export class ProtectedDirective {
   constructor(private authService:AuthService) { ... }
}
```

... and added to one of components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  directives: [ProtectedDirective],
  template: '<div protected></div',
})
export class DashboardCmp { }
```

In console i see an error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for AuthService!
```

If I add a provider to DashboardCmp, everything works fine, but it's not a singleton service. I set its properties in other component and I don't see them when I'm in directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. Everything was fine but

```
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service'; (in protected.directive.ts)
```

is not equal to

```
import {AuthService} from '../Services/auth.service'; ( in main.ts)
```

Yes, it's stupid, but it made the dependency injection impossible.